# Magento: How to change email address for sending error logs?

Tags: email, magento, magento-1.4, error-log

I receive error logs over email, but i change my email account, now i need to change the email also in magento.
Does somebody know where I can find option to change email in magento admin pages to start receive error logs on my new email.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are talking about `errors/local.xml`:

```
<config>
    <report>
        <action>email</action>
        <subject>Store Debug Information</subject>
        <email_address>example@example.com</email_address>
        <trash>leave</trash>
    </report>
</config>
```